# Should I post this question on SO or SU?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about Visual Studio however it doesn't contain any programming material. My question is basically that I installed MVC 2 after installing WebDev 2010 Express and it didn't install the templates and I was just wondering how to install the templates.

Personally I think I should put it on SU, but I feel I may not get a satisfactory anwser due to the nature that there are less programmers on SU.

So should I post IDE related questions on SO or SU?

**EDIT:** Since this is a corner case, I may have a solution. What if I ask the question on SO, then once I've gotten my answer we can all vote to move it to SU. How's that?

Comment: I know this has been asked before. I'd go for SO. This is one of those pesky corner cases.

Comment: Wouldn't migrating the question post-answer kinda deny the rep to the hard working SO folk who answer it?

Comment: @ccornet: I didn't for see that. However it wouldn't take place until after a re-calc would it (not saying that it would be right to take the rep away, I'm just saying)?

Comment: That's only for the rep which happens while it is on SO. If it becomes regarded as extremely helpful and receives a whole bunch of votes once it is in SU... this is a difficult conundrum. Because I do agree that it should fit in SU.

Comment: Migration: I think the right way to look at it is that it would fit as either an SU or an SO question, according to their site mandate's, but that SO has the better audience fit.  So there's no reason to migrate from SO.

Answer (score 7):

Since only programmers would use that tool and it's a tool specifically for programming, I *can't imagine* it would get closed on SO. But I've been wrong before.

Comment: +1 - I know that some will disagree, but I *really* think IDE questions belong on SO.  I know it's a piece of software that you're *using*, not *writing*, but there are just going to be a lot more people on SO who can answer questions about them.

Answer (score 4):

It feels like a SU question, but in terms of best/fastest response and usability of the question *after* it's been answered, SO is the clear choice, IMO.